# I want to search picture from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

firstly, I want to tell you that I am using blob. so, I upload some pics and I'd like to create a search bar so I can call it by `tag` from my database. My case right now is the following:

I can't search 2 words or more.

There is field in my database named `tag` and `kategori`.

In `tag` I put data like `zat ; proses ; obat ;`

It is separated by `;` (semi-colon).

So, here is my code for one search:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "denis", "denis");

mysql_select_db("company");
echo($_POST["tag"]);
?>
<form method="POST" >
<font color='black'>Cari gambar:</font>
<input type="text" name="tag" value=" ">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Cari"/>
</form>
    <?php   
    if(isset ($_POST["tag"]))
    {
    $sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $_GET["id"]." and tag like '%".$_POST["tag"]."%' Order by imageId asc";


    }
    else
    {
    $sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $_GET["id"]." Order by imageId asc limit 1";

    }`enter code here`
    $res2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
    {
        echo("<img src='http://"  . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/profile.php?image_id=". $row2["imageId"]. "' width='15%' height='30%'/>"); 

    }


    mysql_close();
    //echo("ada");
mysql_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I could make it by 2 words or more?

I heard about explode, but I don't understand how to use it.

[this is my database, which use tag to find my image](http://prntscr.com/8viwpe)

Comment: You should have a `tags[tag_id, tag_name]` table to store *single* tags then a `image_tags[tag_id, image_id]` table with one row for each tag a particular image has.  Storing multiple values in a single column never ends well, using a one-to-many table makes things much simpler, you can accomplish what you want with a simple joined query.

Answer (score 1):

use this in mysql query :

```
WHERE interests REGEXP 'tag1|tag2|tag3'
```

Comment: You could expand this answer to show how this query could be built, for example `$tags = str_replace(' ','|',$_POST['tag']);` And a note about sql injection, and normalization would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, I am splitting the tags and generating the like clause for the MySQL query:

```
            $tags = "tag1 tag2 tag2";
            $Id = 1;
            $atags = explode(" ",$tags);
            $mytags = "";
            foreach($atags as $tag)
            {
            $mytags .= " tag like '%". $tag . "%' or";  
            }
            $sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $Id." and ".$mytags."der by imageId asc";
            echo $sql2;
```

Comment: where i have to put this code? im new to this world, so i dont have any idea ..sorry XD

Comment: The code needs to be above your sql2 statement. I gave you the full code to paste into your php file.

Comment: nothing come out .. #sad.. echo result is "select imageId from output_images where bukuId=1 and  tag like '%tag1%' or tag like '%tag2%' or tag like '%tag2%' or Order by imageId asc"

Comment: Adding a new answer and dude seriously this is spoon feeding

Answer (score 0):

Ok what i understand is. You want a search bar where you can enter tags of images. The output/$_POST['tag'] will be like this tag1;tag2

You can use an explode and foreach every tag.

```
$data = explode(';', $_POST['tag']);
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $tags){
$i++;
  if($i == 1){
 $query .= 'AND tag like %'.$tags.'%';
}else{
$query .= 'OR tag like %'.$tags.'%';
}
}

$sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $_GET["id"]." ".$query." Order by imageId asc";
```

this will give you a sql query like this

```
SELECT imageId from output_images where bukuId= '5' AND tag='tag1' OR tag='tag2' Order by  imageId asc
```

**EDIT**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "denis", "denis");

mysql_select_db("company");
echo($_POST["tag"]);
?>
<form method="POST" >
<font color='black'>Cari gambar:</font>
<input type="text" name="tag" value=" ">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Cari"/>
</form>
    <?php   
    if(isset ($_POST["tag"]))
    {
    $data = explode(';', $_POST['tag']);
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $tags){
$i++;
  if($i == 1){
 $query .= 'AND tag like %'.$tags.'%';
}else{
$query .= 'OR tag like %'.$tags.'%';
}
}

$sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $_GET["id"]." ".$query." Order by imageId asc";


    }
    else
    {
    $sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $_GET["id"]." Order by imageId asc limit 1";

    }
    $res2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
    {
        echo("<img src='http://"  . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/profile.php?image_id=". $row2["imageId"]. "' width='15%' height='30%'/>"); 

    }


    mysql_close();
    //echo("ada");
mysql_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

here is your code. YOu will see the changes i have made.

Comment: where i have to put this? im new to php, so i dont really understand about placement.. can i put it at the top? bellow $conn?

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isset ($_POST["tag"]))
        {
        $tags = $_POST["tag"];
        $Id = $_GET["id"];
        $atags = explode(" ",$tags);
        $mytags = "";
        foreach($atags as $tag)
        {
        $mytags .= " tag like '%". $tag . "%' or";  
        }
        $sql2="select imageId from output_images where bukuId=". $Id." and tag like '%".$tags."%' Order by imageId asc";
        }
```

Here is your code modified